# XML file to create list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: search-results

We had a scenario where we are having huge data in the form of xml file which is external to sharepoint site so we need to bring that data in xml to sharepoint site and use it for search purpose.Can we create a list using that xml file so that we can do the crawling in our sharepoint site.Please suggest me few ways for this .Thanks in advnace

Comment: http://whathaveyoutried.com? A simple foreach loop would do the job. Explain what you tried, what you get, error you encountered, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try making a [BDC Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx) for your XML file and make External List for that... You can then use SharePoint Forms as well to manipulate data for your XML

You can deploy the XML file into Layouts folder somewhere and access it from there...

Then you can use [Search with your External List](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/04/28/searching-external-data-in-sharepoint-2010-using-business-connectivity-services.aspx) or [Configure Search for External Content Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg512147%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Too much I guess :-), other way could be load the XML file to SQL Server Database and use BCS, External Content Types with SQL Server database... That will be more feasible, as you will get rid of your XML file.. Database is more easily handleable and other advantages like integrity and so on!

[Custom BDC Model Example for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff623022.aspx)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I like the BDC route, however if you just want to get the data into SharePoint, use PowerShell to read the XML file and load it into a list.

See http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/powershell-faqs/Q-Can-PowerShell-read-and-parse-XML-files for a quick help on how to read an XML file. Then you could mimic this script, but instead of a Excel/CSV, use your XML file and properties http://davidlozzi.com/2012/02/29/loading-sharepoint-lists-from-excel/

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions i will try with bcs and powershell scripting will et back if i have any issues..Thanks alot again.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list instance with visual studio and deploy it.

[List Instances in SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478860.aspx)